# Восстановить указатель стека

Tags: windows, ассемблер, kernel, взлом

Сразу скажу, что делаю всё исключительно в учебных целях.

Пытаюсь разобраться в методах ROP-программирования. Нашел в ядре примерно такой гаджет:

`mov esp, _addr_
 ret`

и передал в него управление.

В `_addr_` у меня лежит подготовленный для некоторой задачи кадр стека (по сути, лежат адреса ROP-гаджетов). И когда я все, что нужно, выполнил, возникает вопрос - а что дальше? Вообще, насколько я понимаю, нужно как-то восстановить указатель стека, но уже 2 дня сижу и придумать ничего не смог.

Comment: Очевидно, нужно записать в esp значение, сохранённое до строки `mov esp, _addr_`.

Comment: Но у меня нет возможности сохранить старый esp

Comment: На нет и суда нет. Хотя - так не бывает. Что значит "нет возможности"?

Comment: Как вы попали в «гаджет»? Безусловным прыжком? Есть ли тогда возможность сохранить `esp` в сегмент данных силами того кода, откуда вы прыгнули в «гаджет»?

Comment: То есть невозможно в таких условиях как-то продолжить работу? Нет возможности - это значит я могу контролировать 1 команду `call`, то есть перейти единожды по некоторому адресу.

Comment: @Arhad нет. Считается, что мне "повезло" и я могу в некоторый `call` подсунуть свой адрес. Больше ничего.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что вы хотите прыгнуть из `call` в «гаджет», затем, после выполнения своего кода, вернуться обратно к этому `call` и продолжить нормальное выполнение программы?

Comment: @Arhad да, примерно так.

Comment: Идея для размышления: если нет возможности получить «гаджет», записывающий `esp` по известному или контролируемому адресу, то можно поискать способ установить обработчик исключения или аппаратного прерывания, а затем как-то это исключение спровоцировать. Всё зависит исключительно от того, какие куски кода можно получить. Согласен, итоговая цепочка переходов может оказаться огромной.

Comment: @Arhad А что мне даёт обработчик этого исключения?

Comment: Ах, да, хотя при аппаратном прерывании и производится переключение на другой стек, этот новый стек тоже необходимо отмотать (о чём я и забыл) в исходное состояние, иначе `iret` вернёт не туда. Каюсь за невнимательность.